# Java Tutorial, this program contains a bug but I could not find it

Tags: java

This program complies but won't run successfully, I am unable to find the bug.

```
public class Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer[]stringBuffers = new StringBuffer[10];

        for(int i =0; i< stringBuffers.length;i++){
            stringBuffers[i].append("StringBuffer at index " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException... too trivial, try to read the stackbacktrace when the program finish

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 6):

You don't initialize your `stringbuffers`.

You should have something like

```
for(int i =0; i< stringBuffers.length;i++){
   stringBuffers[i] = new StringBuffer();
```

or

```
for(int i =0; i< stringBuffers.length;i++){
   stringBuffers[i] = new StringBuffer("StringBuffer at index " + i);
```

Comment: Why do I suddendly, one month later, get my first downvote on this answer ? Did I anger somebody ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to init the StringBuffer:

```
public class Q1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer[]stringBuffers = new StringBuffer[10];

    for(int i =0; i< stringBuffers.length;i++){
        stringBuffers[i]= new StringBuffer();
        stringBuffers[i].append("StringBuffer at index " + i);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `StringBuffer` objects in your array with the required String: -

```
for(int i =0; i< stringBuffers.length;i++){
    stringBuffers[i] = new StringBuffer("StringBuffer at index " + i);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

IN the statement:

```
StringBuffer[]stringBuffers = new StringBuffer[10];
```

you have just created an array of 10 elements. But you have not put any element in it.Each element in this array is still empty  and  by default, contains `null`.

So when you called

```
stringBuffers[i].append("StringBuffer at index " + i);
```

here  `stringBuffers[i]` is still uninitialized and *is pointing to `null`.*

So it is giving `java.lang.NullPointerException.`

As stated in other answers, if you do like this:

```
for(int i =0; i< stringBuffers.length;i++){
   stringBuffers[i] = new StringBuffer();
```

This will initialize each element of stringBuffer array with the *reference* to a StringBuffer object.So  stringBuffer[i] now is not empty.

---

By the way You should use StringBuilder. Both StringBuffer and StringBuilder provides mutable strings. Use StringBuffer only if your application is running in multithreading environment becoz it introduces performance overhead